# Fetch api error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 3 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: javascript, asp.net, fetch-api

I am encountering error using fetch api and it is not hitting my controller action so I can debug.

```
document.querySelector('#save-button').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    let name = document.querySelector('#name').value;
    let title = document.querySelector('#title').value;
    let recipient = document.querySelector('#recipient').value;
    let data = JSON.stringify({ Name: name, Title: title, Recipient: recipient });
    console.log(data);

    fetch('/person/addperson', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;'
        },
        body: data
    })
        .then(function (response) {
            if (response.status !== 200) {
                console.log('fetch returned not ok' + response.status);
            }

            response.json().then(function (data) {
                console.log('data returned');
                console.log(data);
            });
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(`error: ${err}`);
        });
}, false);
```

This is the error I am getting in Firefox console

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 3 column 1 of
>   the JSON data

This is the result of my console log on my data I send to server

```
    {"Name":"myfirstname","Title":"mytitle","Recipient":"myrecipient"}
```

No response because it is not hitting my controller actions in the first place..

When I use jquery, like below there is no problem

```
            $.ajax({
                url: '/person/addperson',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: data,
                type: 'POST',
                beforeSend: function () {
                },
                success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                    if (status == 'success') {
                        console.log('success');
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log('oops');
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr, error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
```

Comment: You might want to use https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44994302/edit to edit/update the question to add the response headers shown in the Network pane of your browser devtools, and probably also include what response body is shown there

Comment: And you might also want to update your question to be more clear, where you say “the result of my console log”, that mean the first console log call in your code, which is just logging the data you’re sending in the request (not the response data).

Comment: How did U solve this?